# want to make the command LS to search only the file

Tags: shell-script, shell

I have two csv files
example

```
t_test_yyyyymmdd.csv
t_test_type_yyyyymmdd.csv
```

I want to make the command ls to search only
the file `t_test_yyyyymmdd.csv`

Comment: Please [edit] your question and clarify. Do you mean you have many files with different dates? Are you just looking for `ls t_test_[0-9]*`?

Comment: Thank you it works very well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to list all files whose name starts with `t_test_` and then has a number, you can use:

```
ls t_test_[0-9]*
```

The `[0-9]` is a character class that matches any number, and the `*` means "one or more times".

Comment: Thank you it works very well

Answer (score -2):

Have you considered using the `|grep` command to help your `ls`?

For example:

```
ls |grep t_test_type_yyyyymmdd.csv
```

`grep` is a very powerful tool for these kind of checks; more information about the `grep` command here: https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/how-to-use-grep.

Comment: Please, not!! --> https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead